# Django - Error Message in Custom Auth Backend

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login

I have written a custom auth backend by extending the defalut ModelBackend. Is it possible to send a custom error message to login screen? As of now it is displaying the default message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages are coming as `ValidationError` exceptions raised by `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`. You would need to extend the Authentication Form or implement your own authentication form to change it's error messages.

Answer (score 5):

You can raise a django ValidationError

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

raise ValidationError("Some custom message")
```

You can then display it with:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors|striptags }}
```

Comment: Note that according to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) your backend should function as following; "_check the credentials it gets, and it should return a User object that matches those credentials, if the credentials are valid. If they’re not valid, it should return None_". Not sure if you were suggesting to raise a `ValidationError` in the backend, but I'm just putting it out there.

Comment: @Bono, though you're right (and I like your music), facing the alternative of having to implement your own form, simply raising a ValidationError within the auth method is awfully simple and just works.

Comment: (of course, the idea is not to throw this for when a user enters "wrong" credentials as-in ones that don't match an existing user, but "wrong" in a sense that is considered invalid because of some other validation logic pertinent for this particular auth backend)