# Django brute force protection

Tags: django

I want a brute force protector for logins that will:

1. block based on username(eventually add ip)
2. store info about failed login to db(username, pwd, user-agent, etc)
3. When locked will tell user that they are locked out

I looked at the following apps:

1. http://code.google.com/p/django-brutebuster/
   In decorators.py the  method returns None when locked so the user gets the “Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive”.  I want the user to know the account is locked out.
2. https://github.com/alexkuhl/django-failedloginblocker
   In decorators.py the  method raises an exception which means if debug=False the user will see a 500 error.
3. http://code.google.com/p/django-axes/
   This doesn't include the user (has ip and user-agent).  In decorators.py  I'm not sure how to get the user name.  Also I'm concerned about the approach of trying to log someone in and then logging them out if the account is locked.  I like the approaches of #1 and #2 where they first check if the account is locked before trying to log them in.

For #1 and #2 I looked into adding the error to the form and I found this post [Django - Error Message in Custom Auth Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523928/django-error-message-in-custom-auth-backend) that says overwrite django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm but I'm not sure how to incorporate the new form in the apps.

Does anyone have suggestions about writing a brute force protector that will do the things I want?

Comment: You could read the source code of the apps you linked and get to understand how they work. Then you could easily write your own.